# Firebase messaging in Android Chrome fails w/ DOMException: Registration failed - push service error on getToken

Tags: android, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please assume user has given permission, browser settings allow notifications, and firebase has been correctly initialized.  **Push notification are working on Chrome desktop.** *This issue relates specifically to Android devices running Chrome.*

```
const messaging = firebaseApp.messaging();

messaging.getToken()
.catch(e => console.log(e)); // DOMException: Registration failed - push service error
```

Comment: I have filed an issue with the firebase-js-sdk here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/152

Comment: I have created an example application documenting the above error here: https://firebase-messaging-error.herokuapp.com/ with the code published here: https://github.com/Matt-Jensen/firebase-messaging-error